# How to automatically create postgis database for Django testing?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm trying to test my Django apps which run on a PostGIS database, by following the info in the [Django testing docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/).

Normally I create a new database by copying a template:

(as user postgres)

```
createdb -T template_postgis -O lizard test_geodjango2
```

When I run `./manage.py test`, I get the following message:

> Creating test database...
> Got an error creating the test database: permission denied to create database
>
> Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_geodjango2', or 'no' to > cancel:

What's the best way to let the system create the database?

Comment: Please include the relevant DATABASE... parameters from your settings.py file.

Answer (score 4):

It may be that your `DATABASE_USER` doesn't have permissions to create a new database/schema.

---

**Edit**

If you read the source for the Django `test` command, you'll see that it always creates a test database.    Further, it modifies your settings to reference this test database.

See this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#id1

What you should do is use [fixtures](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#fixture-loading).  Here's how we do it.

1. From your template database, create a "fixture".  Use the `manage.py dumpdata` command to create a JSON file with all of your template data.  [Hint, the `--indent=2` option gives you readable JSON that you can edit and modify.]
2. Put this in a `fixtures` directory under your application.
3. Reference the fixtures file in your TestCase class definition.  This will load the fixture prior to running the test.

   ```
   class AnimalTestCase(TestCase):
       fixtures = ['mammals.json', 'birds']
       def testFluffyAnimals(self):
            etc.
   ```

The fixtures replace your template database.  You don't need the template anymore once you have the fixtures.

Comment: It's indeed the case. But if I use a user that have permissions, the resulting database will probably not a postgis database? (Because I copy the postgis database from a template)

Answer (score 2):

As S.Lott mentioned, use the standard *test* command.

Using geodjango with postgis you'll need to add the following to your settings for the spatial templates to be created properly.

**settings.py**

```
POSTGIS_SQL_PATH = 'C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\8.3\\share\\contrib'
TEST_RUNNER='django.contrib.gis.tests.run_tests'
```

**console**

```
manage.py test
```

Described here:
http://geodjango.org/docs/testing.html?highlight=testing#testing-geodjango-apps

I haven't looked into it yet, but when I do this I get prompted for the database password when it attempts to install the necessary sql.

Answer (score 0):

As of Django 1.11, Django supports the Postgres-only setting `settings.DATABASE[whatever]['TEST']['TEMPLATE']` that dictates what template the test database is created from:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template